# How to flag incorrect links to data on data.gov?

Tags: usa, data.gov, education

Just looking around, and noticed that the CSV dataset that should be a list of all elementary schools in the US, is actually a population breakdown of Canadian provinces.

http://catalog-next.data.gov/dataset/list-of-elementary-schools

I don't see any way to flag a problem with this dataset...

Comment: Have you tried the [Contact Us](http://www.data.gov/contact-us) form?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with a web site.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I'd say this question is *very much* on topic, especially since I know that we have quite a few  data.gov experts here on Open Data SE. For a detailed discussion about this kind of question, please have a look at http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/124/70

Comment: @PatrickHoefler : and even more importantly, they refer people here for issues ... look on the left side for the bit about 'Questions? Issues?
Join the community on Open Data StackExchange.'

Comment: Is this something StackExchange wants (this site to be a means of support for a `.gov` website) ?

Comment: @Joe Hum. Found that now. I'll go poke that around internally.

Comment: After some internal checking, it's all green with us.

Comment: @E-sushi : I don't think we should be the tech support ... but we also shouldn't be rude to new users for doing what they were told to do.  I've flagged this so that hopefully Jeanne will see it, as one of the moderators on here also works for data.gov.

Comment: @e-sushi : I also don't think that this question is necessarily off-topic.  If you have a whole website that's about the same topic, and someone has a question about problems with that website, we likely need to judge each individual questions rather than outright rejecting them.

Comment: This question is, in my potentially biased opinion, on topic. We are asking people to post questions about where to find open data and how to use it, and getting answers to these types of issues is appropriate. Moreover, the uber-Stack Exchange experts have already weighed in on using this site to help supplement questions on the usage of other sites for "community-driven tech support": http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/124/is-this-an-appropriate-place-for-discussion-of-individual-open-data-tools (I am the Evangelist for Data.gov.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The datasets that you might be looking for are [all school districts](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/list-of-local-education-agencies-school-districts) and/or the [School Universe Survey](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/public-elementarysecondary-school-universe-survey-2009-10). To provide feedback on any of the datasets on Data.gov, you can contact the dataset owner listed on the page (contact email, which in this case is jane.clark@ed.gov) or contact Data.gov at the [contact link](http://www.data.gov/contact-us) at the bottom of every Data.gov page.

The URL you are linking to is for a new concept site on Data.gov (Next.Data.gov) for which we are eliciting feedback on a set of new approaches and user interface. This site is not fully operational, but in this case the link is clearly incorrect and I'll get it fixed right away. The contact listed on this page is Marina Martin at    marina@marinamartin.com.

Comment: "contact Data.gov at the contact link at the bottom of every Data.gov page."

The [contact page](http://www.data.gov/contact) needs help. It supports essentially 3 options: "Ask a question", "Make a Request", "Report a Problem". The problem reported above is clearly a a problem, but if one follows that link currently (5 Mar 2015), one receives only the suboption to "Report a problem with the website", i.e. to put an issue on the website code. data.gov should provide an option to mark a dataset as misclassified when it clearly is.

Comment: Thanks @TomRoche.  I've added an issue to the Github repository to have the Data.gov team fix this: https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/603